# how to remove white space at the top when doing a print styles

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How do you remove the white space at the top when you print. I'm doing print styles using print.css files. When i preview the print there is a white space at the top. How do i remove that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a live view of your site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
@media print {
body, html {
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}
}
```

You could write this directly in your default style.css file.

Answer (score 2):

Css rules, Try this

```
@ media print{
body{
margin-top:0px;padding-top:0px;
}
}
```

Comment: what about a negative margin ?

Comment: i also tried that, but it ends up cutting off the top of the logo

Comment: Where is the whitespace ? above the logo or below ? could you move the logo upwards then add negative margin to the rest of the page to move it up aswell ?

Comment: Billy, the whitespace is above the logo, its like a 50-60px whitespace at the top

Comment: What happens if you move the logo up by 50px, i.e. `#logo{position:relative;top:-50px;}`

Comment: same things, gets cut off. so weird

Comment: try using cm or mm CSS units, I've just seen somewhere that using px may affect print styles

Comment: cm and mm just makes my logo disapear from the print style

Comment: I think you're gonna have to post some of your code, as I'm out at the minute and on a library computer I won't be able to try and muck around with it but others might. I'll have a look later when I'm home. One last idea, Is your logo an image? Does the image have the whitespace?

Comment: yes, my logo is an image. Even when i remove the image the text underneath the still dosen't sit at the top of the page and still has the white space at the top. I checked the code and there is nothing else displaying above the image.

Comment: I think you'll have to post at least the top part of your code

Comment: Back again, on my comp now. Try linking to a different css sheet in the html file with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">` To make sure that no other rules are conflicting with the @media print.